# Replace all '-' in a url

Tags: javascript

my code now only replaces the first `-` with space, but there are multiple `-` in the url, how do I replace all with space?

```
window.location.hash.substring(1).replace('-', ' ');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
window.location.hash.substring(1).replace(/-/g, ' ')
```

g -> all instances

Comment: Perfect thank you! Will tick your answer when the time is up.